# Install SynEdit into Delphi 2010 - SynEdit_R2010.bpl is missing

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, synedit

I am attempting to install SynEdit_D2010 into my Delphi 2010 IDE, and I get an error stating that the program can't start because **SynEdit_R2010.bpl** is missing from my system.

As far as I can tell, **SynEdit_R2010.bpl** is not missing on my system, and I even have it in my `$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Bpl` directory. However, for some reason Delphi doesn't seem to think it is there!

Any ideas how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure all your directories are correctly defined ?

I think the BPL has to be visible in the project.

Comment: You are correct, I had to add the path to the location of SynEdit_R2010.bpl to the project search path of my SynEdit_D2010 project.

Installing some of this stuff into the Delphi IDE is a little complex, but once I learned to go to Project -> Options -> Directories and Conditionals and add the location of the .bpl to the project search path, all was well.

Thanks for your answer!