# Installing SynEdit gives errors

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, failed-installation, synedit

I have been trying to install SynEdit for the last two weeks but no luck. i downloaded its latest version, (I have Delphi XE2), extracted it, went to the packages folder, opened *DelphiXE2.groupproj*. Delphi IDE started, in the project manager, I right clicked  *SynEdit_RXE2.bpl* and build it (succesful).

Then build *SynEdit_DXE2.bpl* but this time it gave error. This is it:

For this line:

```
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}
```

It says

> [DCC Fatal Error] SynEdit_RXE2.dpk(30): E2225 Never-build package 'designide' must be recompiled

And below this it says:

> [DCC Fatal Error] SynEdit_DXE2.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'SynEdit_RXE2' not found

Please tell me how to install it correctly.

Comment: You did  see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9984900/62576), right? That will solve your second error. Search here for *never build package*, as that issue has come up here before as well.

Comment: I did see it, but  that didn't solve the problem 'at all'.

Comment: It solves the *second one*, just as I said. The solution to the first can be found by searching as I said.

Comment: Nothing happens. The problem is still as it was.

Comment: Now what did I do that I was down repped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions:

1. Clone the github repo: https://github.com/SynEdit/SynEdit
2. Open the XE2 group project in `Packages\DelphiXE2.groupproj`.
3. Add `SynHighlighterJSON` to `SynEdit_DXE2`. It is used by `SynEdit_RXE2` and is, as I write this answer, missing from `SynEdit_DXE2`.
4. Build both projects in the project group, for instance by using *Project | Build All Projects*.
5. Install the design time package `SynEdit_DXE2`.

Since the project did not build without modifications, I suspect that the testing on older Delphi versions is not as comprehensive as it should be. However, I have just followed the steps above, and successfully installed the library.